# EJB test & Arquillian - Struts + JEE6 + EJB3

Tags: java, struts, ejb-3.0, jboss-arquillian, jboss-eap-6

I work in a old system, with Jboss EAP 6.1 + EJB 3 + Struts... I would like to write tests for this system... I was studying Arquillian, but I don't find any example without CDI and with older technologies ... I want to test this old system and I have EJBs, I need to use container...

Do you think is Arquillian will usefull in my case?
What is best way to test EJBs with this technologies ?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arquillian fully supports EJB 3.0.

You can inject your EJBs into the tests.
If you are using even older EJB code which does not support injection, you can even use inital context and lookup your EJBs in your tests.
I have been thoroughly using Arquillian to test EJBs.

Comment: Do you think it is usefull to use without CDI? :-)

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily test the system bottom up without the need for Arquillian. There are three type of test you may want to write.

1. Unit tests
2. Integration tests
3. System tests
4. Functional tests

With functional tests being manual.

You write **unit tests** without any container, because you are testing at a method level.

**Integration tests** may not use any container, you can simulate the container behavior in some cases:

```
@Stateless
public class Cat {

    @PostContruct
    void init() { 

        say("Meow");

    }

    public void say(String output) {

        System.out.println(output);

    }

}
```

Writing a test is simple enough:

```
String catOutput = "";

@Test public void cat_shouldSayMeow_whenInstantiated {
    Cat cat = new Cat();
    assertEquals("Meow", catOutput);
}

public class CatInSimulatedContainer extends Cat {
    public CatInSimulatedContainer() {
        super.init(); // <--- the container would run this automatically after injection
    }

    @Override
    public void say(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}
```

And finally, your **system tests** can use the “real” container, in your case JBoss, to be tested. All you need to do is install Jenkins and instruct him to regularly run the tests.

No need for chubby Arquillian :)